# Facebook Instant Games - Can I use the image library in my instant game

Tags: facebook-instant-games

Is it possible to get access to the photos library in the Instant Game? 
If not, are there any other methods that I can pull a selected image from a user who's using my instant game app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to get access to the image library or Facebook photos of the user from Instant Games, except the profile picture of the user and their friends.